Two Phone numbers for Whatsapp
I am moving from New Zealand to Australia.  So for the next year, I have a mobile number in each country.
**Whatsapp is linked to my NZ number. Will it keep working for my new contacts on the new mobile number as well as the old contacts on the discarded mobile number.

There should be only one question per post. All these questions might be more appropriate for a site where mobile apps are on-topic like [android.se].

I thought I had asked only one question and given three reasons for asking.  Anyhow, I have edited it.  It's not really an Android specific question.

In contrast to other cross-platform apps, WhatsApp requires Android or iPhone

You will be able to access your old contacts while you have their numbers in your device, but you might not have access to the old messages.
It's not possible to have one WhatsApp account with two phone numbers, however a working phone number is required only for phone number verification.
Check if the carrier of your NZ phone number has international roaming as it might be required when it be required to verify it while you be off shores.
Check if your device allow having dual apps as this might allow to have two intances of WhatsApp, each with their own phone number.
P.D.

I have used WhatsApp while being  in Asia, Europe, North and South América with and without using international roaming.
I'm handling two phone numbers in the same device, which supports two SIMs, using dual apps.
WhatsApp has a feature to change  the account phone number.


I have had both my numbers on roaming for the last month. Whatsapp seems to be working fine.  I had expected it to perhaps create two contacts (and message streams), but it has only one stream - tested with my wife and a friend.  Possibly the caveat is that my contacts have to have both my numbers against my entry.
I still don't know what happens when I finally lay my NZ number to rest.
